# Kernel headers location

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, header, linux-device-driver

I try to compile a Linux Kernel module (a driver for a Wi-Fi adapter) for my Lenovo IdeaTab S6000 tablet. However, Android 4.2.2 has an old kernel (3.4.5), and it is hard to find kernel headers for it. I have downloaded [official open source code for it](http://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds00313) (which is, by the way, incomplete as other people say). Where can I find kernel headers there?

P.S. I try to build the Atheros 9271 driver (ath9k), and the `make` command needs `/lib/modules/3.4.5/build`.

Comment: you can install linux header for particualr kernel version by using "sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)"

Comment: If that was possible, I would have already done it. 1) They are not present in repos. 2) Headers for Android devices are usually modified, not vanilla.

Comment: It seems that you want to cross compile Linux Kernel module for Android device. Try [this](http://yatsec.blogspot.in/2011/01/guide-to-compiling-custom-kernel.html)

Comment: Seems to be what I need; is it possible to compile a module on the device itself, not on a PC? I've got complete Kali Linux installation on my tablet.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that work on Tablet. But I would suggest you to do it on Laptop or PC as it gives you more flexibility and debugging resources.

Comment: I have prepared all the required files, but when I use `./adb pull /proc/config.gz`,  I get the following error :
`remote object '/proc/config.gz' does not exist`. How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to get sources first, otherwise it's a difficult task to perform.

Comment: I do have sources; but what about the issue I an experiencing?